# Adding multiple subviews to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I've been messing around and trying to make my own messaging application (for practice).
I'm adding a custom `UIView` to a standard `UIScrollView` based on an `IBAction`.

Each time the user presses a button, I do the following (in order):

- Enumerate the subviews in the scrollView and increase the value of an
  integer. I use this `int` to set the y-position of the new custom
  view
- Create a custom `UIView` with a frame size that varies only in width. The view has a `UILabel` on top of it that has the text.
- Create a new `CGSize` that I use to set the `contentSize` of the
  `UIScrollView`. The new `CGSize` is the width of the scrollView + the
  height of the custom view + some padding.
- I then set the contentSize of the scrollView.
- I then add the custom view as a subview of the scrollView.

I created a timer that adds a new message/subview every two seconds to test multiple messages and **the issue I am seeing is that once the subviews are added outside the viewable area of the `UIScrollView`, they stop being added**. They are only added once I bring the messages back into the viewable area, and even so, they are added overlaying at times.

Now, I am aware of a few things: I need to add the subviews on a separate thread since they won't be added while the user is scrolling. I know that I will need to "clean up" subviews as they build up since my app will keep eating memory as more subviews are added. I am also aware that I should reposition the `UIScrollView` as messages are added since it doesn't make sense to add them outside of the viewable area. Finally, I don't think enumerating the subviews is very elegant... so I will change that later... nor is the temp `UILabel` I make... Now for some code:

```
- (void)pushMyMessage:(NSString *)message
{
UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
tempLabel.text = message;
[tempLabel sizeToFit];

//adding the new message as a subview below any previous messages
    if (self.messageView.subviews.count > 0)
    {
        int yIndex = 0;

        for (SDMessageView *view in self.messageView.subviews)
        {
        //increase the y value for the frame of the next message
        yIndex += view.frame.size.height;
        //add a little padding
        yIndex += 5;
        }

    SDMessageView *newMessage = [[SDMessageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, yIndex, tempLabel.frame.size.width + 8, tempLabel.frame.size.height) setMessage:message];
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.messageView.frame.size.width, self.messageView.contentSize.height + newMessage.frame.size.height + 30);
    [self.messageView setContentSize:newSize];
    [self.messageView addSubview:newMessage];
    }
else
    {
    //initial message
    SDMessageView *newMessage = [[SDMessageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, tempLabel.frame.size.width + 8, tempLabel.frame.size.height) setMessage:message];
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.messageView.frame.size.width, self.messageView.contentSize.height + newMessage.frame.size.height + 30);
    [self.messageView setContentSize:newSize];
    [self.messageView addSubview:newMessage];
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why the subviews are only added while in view? Also, any ideas on how I can do this efficiently?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I would suggest that you should use UITableView instead of scrollview, and in a cell set your message view, using table view it will be very easy to manage UI. I found some links on which you can see some iOS native message application like UI, you can modify it,  and can use as per your need. 1) http://maniacdev.com/2013/03/open-source-ios-control-providing-an-easy-to-implement-messages-app-like-user-interface 2) http://maniacdev.com/2012/08/open-source-custom-ios-uitableview-control-for-chat-bubbles-like-the-messages-app

Comment: @VishwaPatel - awesome. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Few things I noticed while reading your post:

1. You should not make any UI interface changes (like adding subviews) on secondary thread, this should be done on main thread.
2. Why don't you use `UITableView` for displaying messages? If you use table view, you don't have to calculate all the frames, content sizes and etc., just need to give correct height to the cell, and this would efficient way of solving what you are trying to achieve.
3. I didn't really understand, why your subviews are not added to the hidden area of the scroll view, in my practice, I didn't notice such a behaviour of the scroll view (I used it a lot), there should be some other issue with your code (are you adding subviews on secondary thread?).

Hope this was helpful, Good Luck!

Comment: 1. Really? I figured adding the subviews on a secondary thread would give the user the power to continue scrolling up/down or go to a new tab. The messages are sent to a server right before the message/subview is added to the screen... I'm not sure what is the best practice there.
2. I completely overlooked `UITableView`. I will most likely switch to that.
3. The only thing I can think of is how I am calculating the yIndex that positions the new subview. Either that, or it's a bug with the simulator. I am stuck using the simulator till I renew my Dev account.